# Excel - Error with vlookup across multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, for-loop, vlookup, vba

My following code displays error message "Application-defined or object-defined error", and I'm not sure why. Can you please have a look and help me solve the problem?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

j = 3

For i = 1 To 46

Sheets("Income").Range(Cells(6, j), Cells(51, j)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B6,[" & Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx]2 Intercompany markup!$A$1:$E$70,4,FALSE)"

j = j + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using that syntax to define your ranges on the "Income" sheet, you need to specify the sheet for both the `.Range` and the `(Cells(x,y))`.

You should also declare your variables.

It can get ridiculous typing the fully qualified sheet name each time, so you should also declare a worksheet variable.

Try this:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Income")
    j = 3

    For i = 1 To 46

        ws.Range(ws.Cells(6, j), ws.Cells(51, j)).Formula = _
            "=VLOOKUP($B6,[" & ws.Cells(5, i + 2).Value & ".xlsx]2 Intercompany markup!$A$1:$E$70,4,FALSE)"
        j = j + 1

    Next i
```

Comment: Now it's already working much better! Thanks :) However, I get a random other error - after a few columns are finished via the macro, it suddenly would not recognize the path of the next workbook, although it's in exactly the same location as the others. Would you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I believe that's a different issue. Your best best is to describe that issue in another question along with the code and where it is failing. Make sure to include the error.

Comment: The thing is no direct "error" occurs; it's quite peculiar really. You would have the correct file name e.g. [test.xlsx] including the correct sheet reference, but Excel would open a browser window as it doesn't recognise the location, although it's in the same location as the other workbooks that were recognised. Would you happen to know what this could be? Otherwise I'll address this as you suggested. In any event, thanks!

Comment: Does the behavior happen at the same time each time you run it? If so, you can step through the code (using F8 in the code window) and examine your variables at the time it happens. That should probably help you figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I don't know what the issue was, but the problem just resolved itself somehow - works perfect, thank you :)